# ST Nucleo board vs Disco board vs Eval board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

What are the main differences between ST Nucleo boards, Disco boards and Eval boards and what is the main usage for each of them?

Comment: What kind of differences you mean? Does the ST website not provide enough info to compare the board differences and purposes?

Comment: @Justme Thanks for reply. I really need to know what is the main purpose for each of them to use.

Comment: advertising samples that you buy

Comment: [STM32 MCU & MPU Eval Tools](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools.html)

Answer (score 1):

the Discovery boards were the early low cost evaluation boards for select members of the STM32 family. The popular stm32f427 was an early pick for me. No usb->serial via USB which i found annoying.

Then came the Nucleo series that have Arduino headers and have debugger and usb->serial features. There’s also MBED support.

The eval boards tend to be more specific. Eg touch screen lcd. Generally at a higher price point.

For hobbyist use, the Nucleo series would be my suggestion. Just plug into USB, load the IDE and off you go.

Note the above is my general assesment. There’s also STM8 boards labelled as discovery as well.

Comment: Just thought I’d mention I’ve found the STM32L4 discovery boards do have usb->serial features which is nice, but the STM32F4 discovery boards do not

Comment: There was always going to be exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

**Nucleo boards:**

++ Arduino pin-out compatible. you can use some compatible Arduino shields on the nucleo boards.

++ pin to pin compatible with other nucleo boards with the same pin count; feature wise. there is 2 rows of ST MORPHO pin headers which have predefined pin connections (e.g. all nucleo 64 boards have the same pinout, independent of the microcontroller used, with exceptions for a few particular pins). the pin numbers are not same essentially but the peripheral type (SPI, I2C, ...) compatibility is supported.

-- just a microcontroller and a debugger. there are some board-specific things like on-board smps or preinstalled oscillators. nothing more. no fancy stuff like sensors or displays.

**Discovery boards:**

-- no pin-compatibility with other boards or models.

++ there are other devices available on the board for evaluation depending on the model. e.g. accelerometer sensors, LCDs, touch panels, audio chips.

Comment: Some discovery boards (STM32H7B3I-DK is the one I am using) have arduino headers on the board too.  While the discovery boards are more expensive then the nucleos, they are still an exceptional deal.  The nucleos are so cheap I keep a couple from every STM32 processor family on hand just in case I need to check performance or do a quick prototype.